# How to color area when x values are pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got the following line diagram with two time series values and two vertical lines and would like to colour the area where "FromGen" is larger than "ToCons" and on the outside of the two vertical lines.

```
start_date="2019-06-18"
end_date="2019-06-19"

x0='2019-06-18 9:00:00'
x1='2019-06-18 17:00:00'

x1= pd.to_datetime(x1, format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True)
x2= pd.to_datetime(x2, format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True)

zeit = (df['DateTime'] > start_date) & (df['DateTime'] <= end_date)
zeit = df.loc[zeit]

zeit.plot(figsize=(15,10),x="DateTime", y=["FromGen", "ToCons"])
plt.xlabel("Zeit") 
plt.ylabel("Wh")
legend = plt.legend(title="comp",
                    loc=1, fontsize='large', fancybox=True,  labels=['FromGen', 'ToCons'])
plt.axvline(x=x0, color='red')
plt.axvline(x=x1, color='red')

kde_x, kde_y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
ax.fill_between(kde_x, kde_y, where=(kde_x<x0) | (kde_x>x1) , 
                interpolate=True, color='#8FF536')
plt.show()
```

I already found that the code on the last few lines might be helpful - but at the moment I'm struggeling with this error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Many thanks in advance!

[image: Green area should be coloured]

EDIT:
This is how my code looks at the moment- if I don't convert the df into the correct tz everything works perfect. But when I do the green area gets moved. I guess that I'm missing a Timezone convert somewhere but can't find out where....

from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

df= pd.read_csv("filename.csv", error_bad_lines=False, sep=";")
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True)

#df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
#Works great without this line! But when I use it the coloured area seems to be in the wrong timezone

```
start_date = "2019-06-18" end_date = "2019-06-19"

x0 = '2019-06-18 9:00:00' x1 = '2019-06-18 16:00:00'


zeit = df.loc[(df['DateTime'] > start_date) & (df['DateTime'] <= end_date)]

ax = zeit.plot(figsize=(15, 10), x="DateTime", y=["FromGen", "ToCons"])

ax.set_xlabel("Zeit") ax.set_ylabel("Wh") legend = ax.legend(title="comp",
                   loc='upper right', fontsize='large', fancybox=True, labels=['FromGen', 'ToCons']) ax.axvline(x=x0, color='red') ax.axvline(x=x1, color='red')

x0 = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))

ax.fill_between(zeit['DateTime'].values, zeit['FromGen'], zeit['ToCons'],
                where=((zeit['FromGen'] > zeit['ToCons']) & ((zeit['DateTime'] <= x0) | (zeit['DateTime'] >=x1))),
                interpolate=False, color='#8FF536') plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with dates has evolved a lot in the last pandas and matplotlib versions. Therefore, referring to old posts can be misleading. The following code has been tested with matplotlib 3.4.1 and pandas 1.2.4.

Something strange in the code of the question, is that first `x0` and `x1` are used, and thereafter `x1` and `x2` without giving a value to `x2`.

`plt.fill_between()` can work directly with the numerical columns. To work with the datatime column, now it is happy with `...['DateTime'].values`. For the `where` clause, to compare the datetime column, the x0 and x1 need to be converted with `pd.to_datetime(...)`. As the datetime values in my example don't have `utc`, the comparison doesn't work when using `x0 = pd.to_datetime(..., utc=True)`.

Also note that pandas plotting (`zeit.plot(...)`) returns a matplotlib `ax`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start_date = "2019-06-18"
end_date = "2019-06-19"

x0 = '2019-06-18 9:00:00'
x1 = '2019-06-18 17:00:00'

N = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': pd.date_range(start_date, freq='10min', periods=N),
                   'FromGen': 8 * np.exp(-(np.arange(N) - 80) ** 2 / 1000) + np.random.uniform(0, 0.4, N),
                   'ToCons': np.random.uniform(1, 1.5, N)})

x0 = pd.to_datetime(x0, format="%Y-%m-%d")
x1 = pd.to_datetime(x1, format="%Y-%m-%d")

zeit = df.loc[(df['DateTime'] > start_date) & (df['DateTime'] <= end_date)]

ax = zeit.plot(figsize=(15, 10), x="DateTime", y=["FromGen", "ToCons"])

ax.set_xlabel("Zeit")
ax.set_ylabel("Wh")
legend = ax.legend(title="comp",
                   loc='upper right', fontsize='large', fancybox=True, labels=['FromGen', 'ToCons'])
ax.axvline(x=x0, color='red')
ax.axvline(x=x1, color='red')

ax.fill_between(zeit['DateTime'].values, zeit['FromGen'], zeit['ToCons'],
                where=(zeit['FromGen'] > zeit['ToCons']) & ((zeit['DateTime'] <= x0) | (zeit['DateTime'] >= x1)),
                interpolate=False, color='#8FF536')
plt.show()
```

[image: fill_between with pandas datetime]

Comment: Could you please specify where I need to use the pd.to_datetime(..., utc=True) ? might this solve my problem regarding the timezone?

Comment: If your datetimes have a timezone, you probably need `x0 = pd.to_datetime(x0, format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True)`. What is your exact problem with the timezone? How is your dataframe created?

Comment: My df comes from a csv file and I worked a lot with this data yet, so the datetime should be fine.  I already tried many diff. varieties like:

```

ax.fill_between(zeit['DateTime'].values, zeit['FromGen'], zeit['ToCons'],
                where=(zeit['FromGen'] > zeit['ToCons']) & ((zeit['DateTime'] <= pd.to_datetime(x0, format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True)) | (zeit['DateTime'] >= pd.to_datetime(x1, format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True))),
                interpolate=False, color='#8FF536')

```
Here you can check how my plot looks at the moment: https://www.imagebanana.com/s/2079/Bn9Eu1Mg.html

Comment: The comments are not meant to put code blocks. Better to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67405952/edit) it to your question's post. Your image indicates the times are shifted. If you are working with time zones, the correct zone should be set somewhere ([docs[(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)) and be the same as when reading the dataframe. Also note that the brackets in `where=(...) ` are wrong: the `|` needs to be grouped together.

Comment: okay, thanks for your advice I edited my original post. brackets should be fine now I hope :)